# How much will be the performance difference between using own xml parser and system.xml namespace

Tags: c#, xml, optimization, xml-parsing, game-engine

I am trying to write a xml parser  for my game, since the size of the final build increase by 1+ mb when using the `system.xml` namespace. The parser class is a singleton and will be ready for access anytime in the game. Though the amount of data I am going to handle is not much, I am still worried about the performance (since it is a game, I cannot afford to sacrifice any performance).

Is there any way to effectively handle the parsing. Btw i am using c# and if a tag named `<tag>` is there, I am just breaking down the string into pieces searching for `<tag>` and `</tag>`. This will continue recursively until the whole string is broken down  completely. And the result will be saved in a jagged list class I have created.

Are there any ways, I can improve my method or should I just go with System.XML name space.

Also another note: The xml data is from server not from a local file.

Comment: If you could write your own xml parser that is more robust and fault tolerant than the tools provided in System.Xml, you would be working at Microsoft, and not asking questions here.

Comment: @GrayFox374 - Very often, writing a general tool is much more difficult than a specialized tool. For example: maybe the OP does not need to support schemas? Or has only attributes, and not inner text? Or needs only to read XML, and never write it? Also, when you write a library you should think well about all optimization - they depend on common use case.

Comment: @Flamy - Are you sure you need xml? Maybe you could use your own inner format, that could be parsed by your own parser and contain less redundant data...I doubt if one could easily write a xml parser better than Microsoft

Comment: @Kobi If you omit any of that (except writing, I suppose), what you end up with isn't an XML parser, and this question asks about creating an XML parser. You may well be right that that's the question Flamy meant to ask, though.

Comment: yeah @Kobi is correct, my xml doesnt have  attributes, just the inner text.  And it doesnt need all the functionality of XML. more over i never said the performance of what i have written is better than System.XML,  but i was asking if i follow that method, will it be a huge drop in performance. I am ready to sacrifice some performance  for build size, but shouldnt have huge impact.


But my main concern is the 1+ mb size increase of the final build.

Comment: @horgh It has to be XML, cant be helped; we dont have any control over the server data. We just have to process them in game. That is what making it hard for us.

Comment: Since your requirement is pretty straight forward you should go ahead with using System.XML. As @Luixv says, don't re-invent the wheel when there is one, perfectly suiting the needs, serves the puropose. Put the 1+ mb issue aside and look at the support you get from MS when using System.xml. Think also about the support you have to provide when you write your own parser!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes (this should be a comment, but is too long):

1. I could not reproduce your problem. Using a console application, I added a reference to `System.Xml`, created an `XmlDocument`, used it, and compiled, and didn't see any meaningful increase in size.
2. `System.Xml` is part of the .Net base class library. Generally, you can count on it being on every machine that runs .Net (according the msdn, [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) is available in XNA, for example, but not on the portable class library).
3. If it is a part of your framework, make sure you did not set [Copy Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c.aspx) = True on the reference. The default should be false, but if it is true, it will copy a 900 KB DLL to your target folder.
4. No one can ever answer which is faster - The answer is extremely relative - to what types of XMLs  (small? large?)? On what types of machines? What operations will your users do more with these XMLs? Only you can answer these questions, by profiling your code.
5. Even if you discover XmlDocument is slow or too large, there are countless [XML parsers](http://nuget.org/packages?q=parse%20xml) for .Net - maybe one of them is good for you. (even .Net has `XDocument`, but it also requires `System.Xml.dll`, so no gain there)
6. **Generally**, multiple string manipulations are slow. If the method you describe is constantly searching and splitting the sting, it *sounds* slow - I doubt you need to scan the string more than once to parse XML.

Comment: ah you saved my day,   it is as you said in the point 3, I didnt think i messed it up big time.  now the build size is normal even after using System.XML.XMLDocument class.  In fact the build size is far less compared to what it was.

     Thanks for the help again :)

Comment: @Flamy - No problem! This is why it always worth it to also mention the "simple" answers - start with the basics `:)` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not do that. I mean. There are tools already there which are reliable. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible that you can write a faster XML parser, especially if yours has less features. If it does less and is less robust, then it should be faster. I would caution against this, though, because once one part of your application claims to "support XML" but only does so partially, then it may break in the future if your XML producer decides to start adding things that your parser doesn't support but any normal XML parser would.

I ran across this before, from the other direction. We needed to augment the data we sent to an embedded device and decided to add some attributes that we could read later. We were surprised when we discovered that the device couldn't read our data. It turns out that the parser was completely home-grown and could hardly be considered a true XML parser since it required tags to be on separate lines and broke when attributes were added.

Just be cautious if you roll your own parser, which will probably not be nearly as robust as the stock .NET parser, that you communicate exactly what you do and do not support.

Comment: I am completely aware of the problem you are mentioning.       and regarding the features, the XML data doesnt have attributes (as of now), only inner text that has to be read and added to a list.